# Windows 10 Edge not fullsceen on startup

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge, fullscreen

How can I get PowerShell open browser fullsceen (as if you pressed <kbd>F11</kbd>)?

I am using a PowerShell script which works fine if I execute, I'm also using a program called Autostart tool to automate the process. Once Windows loads, the script runs, but browser is not fullscreen.

Comment: Please [edit] and add the script to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `--start-fullscreen` switch which is common for Chromium-based browsers. For example:

```
msedge --start-fullscreen
```

**Note**: this only opens in fullscreen if there isn't already a window open. If there's one, then you need to use:

```
msedge --kiosk https://somewebsite.com --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift response

This is the script im using. Where would i insert  msedge --start-fullscreen

start microsoft-edge:https://netflix.com/browse

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;

$wshell.AppActivate('edge') 

while ($true)
{
    Sleep 2
    $wshell.SendKeys('{f11}')
    exit 
}

exit

Comment: You need to add additional info like this into the question itself by editing it. Is this some script you copied from somewhere? It tries to press F11 in browser, which you don't need if you do what I wrote.

Comment: Sorry im not so clued when it comes to scripts.....Yes i got that script from Stackoverflow......Do you perhaps know how to fullscreen edge whilst in kiosk mode?That will solve all my issues.

Comment: See the updated 2nd command. Just run that command in PowerShell/Autostart, assuming you have `msedge.exe` in `%PATH%`. If not, either edit `PATH` env var to include `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application` or use full path like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"` instead of `msedge` in the command.